# C# Change all the buttons' background color at once

Tags: c#, button, colors, background

I have a seat reservation app for an airport transport bus. I enter the name of the passenger in a textbox, then I click on one of the buttons (seats), and then it changes its color from Green to Red, and displays the folowing message: "The seat is reserved for 'name entered'." If I didn't entered a name in the textbox, it displays the following message: "Please enter a name."
I would like to make an easter egg. If I would enter a specific name, it should reserve all the seats and change all the buttons' background color to red at once, but I failed on coding that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, well perhaps you should show us the code that fails so we can point you the problem

Comment: I recommend to enhance your question. The answer depends on how exactly your UI is currently implemented and as @Steve mentioned, it is a good practice to share the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WinForms, you can use this:

```
using System.Linq;
```

```
private void SetButtonsBackColorToRed()
{
  foreach ( var button in Controls.OfType<Button>() )
    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

This gets all controls of the form of Button type and parse the resulting list to change the back color.

*Alternative*

```
Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(button => button.BackColor = Color.Red);
```